# Should I use plumbers putty to install a sink drain?

Tags: plumbing, drain

I'm installing a Push Button (not pop-up) drain in my pedestal sink.  A rubber washer goes between the metal drain and the sink (another rubber washer goes under the sink).  Is it still appropriate to use plumbers putty in this situation?

Answer (score 9):

Increasingly, I'm finding that plumber's putty is **not** recommended for sink drains, especially if it has its own rubber gasket. In places where the manufacturer does not supply a gasket (and the flange is not metal) they suggest silicone caulk.

Be sure to read the directions for your drain assembly!

Comment: When I last installed a sink in my home, I used plumber's putty per manufacturer's instructions.  The drain leaked.  I redid the whole thing with more putty.  The drain leaked.  I redid it *again* with silicone and it's been dry ever since.

Comment: Funny I have never had a leak with putty on hundreds of sinks in stone, metal plastic,,,etc if the drain has a gasket it would be silly to waste putty,

Comment: Isn't silicone caulk prone to failure with standing water?

Comment: @Alex Not a pure silicone caulk, no. There is siliconized latex caulk, but that isn't the same thing

Answer (score 3):

I would not use putty. Be sure the bottom of the sink is clean and smooth.The rubber gasket should be sufficient to seal without putty.

Comment: Could you add some reasoning why you wouldn't use putty? Your answer is not that good without it...

Comment: The last sentence explains why--it's simply not needed (and therefore wasteful of time and treasure).

Answer (score 2):

I have always used plumber's putty. Never had leaks at that point and agree with the person who said it allows a more flush fit.

Do not use cooking oil if you use the rubber gasket. Use silicone based valve grease. It will keep the rubber supple over time, is compatible with rubber  and will keep the rubber from deformity during the installation. Though if you use a proper drain wrench, the drain should not be rotating. The nut on the bottom side rotates. Same is true when using plumber's putty. If the drain is rotating, that is likely the reason people are getting leaks using putty.

You want the drain portion to pull down evenly as the nut is firmed up from below. If you are cocking the drain off vertical due to careless installation, or uneven putty ring to start, that can cause a leak too as the drain does not seat evenly and properly.

Be sure to not be too stingy with the putty ring. Make sure you kneed, warm and roll the putty before making the ring around the underside of the drain flange and press well into place. When you install the drain, gently, firmly and keeping drain plumb (vertical and perpendicular to the sink, press the drain down to start the putty squish and form a seal then tighten the nut.

Be sure the the sink is spotlessly clean and smooth before installation. I usually do a final clean with 91% isopropyl rubbing alcohol. Be sure to let it dry thoroughly and do a final wipe with a high quality paper towel or clean dry paper "shop towel".

Putty has been around forever and works very well. I have never seen it leak if installed properly.

Also, make sure the putty is compatible with the material of the sink. On rare occasions, there may be some potential staining, some say, but I have never had an issue with that either.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless it leaks.

I've installed a couple of sink wastes with supplied foam washers that compress down to almost nothing. They were very effective (I first thoroughly cleaned the old putty completely away from the porcelain).

Answer (score 0):

Of the few drains I’ve installed, I always discarded the top rubber foam-like seal. The main reason for this is that the drain will sit slightly lower, hardly leaving a gap between top of the drain and sink. This allows the water to drain completely, instead of a small amount of water remaining around the drain seal. This way, in time, there will be no dry water stain around the drain seal.

Comment: The seal usually goes _below_ the sink. Throwing away purposely-designed parts seems foolish to me.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a the rubber seal on top and the bottom if i had an extra . Put a little cooking oil on the rubber both sides to keep it bind free ( like an oil filter) and torque down till the rubber starts to oval on the outside edge . (plumbers putty solidifies over time under high hot water heater settings and cracks at cold water expansion and contraction and allows the leaks .

Answer (score 0):

I have been increasing the amount of service calls on lavatory drains and others due to the use of silicone. It will not seat the flange properly, it makes a mess and a lot of DIY’s read in instructions to use this then you run into more problems. I can’t count how many times now I have been called to a bathroom leak under a sink now that they recommend silicone on the sink flange. Where home owners have used the silicone on the slip joints and any and everywhere you can imagine. Silicone is also very expensive compared to plumbers putty. But on the bright side service call easy no sweat involved work has really picked up due to this change in install method. Also through away the rubber or foam seal if it comes with one that would go between the flange and sink basin it causes the flange to sit above the bottom of sink and not flush that will not allow for all water and debris to drain. This small amount of waste causes a lot of long term problems as well as having to constantly wipe out the sink. However it’s another reason I have had increased service calls. You can say what you like about plumbers putty but very very rare have I had a repair call that in any way involved the use of putty. And if it did it was because the system was 15 plus years old time to replace anyways. I also agree you can’t seal a threaded pipe by screwing them together with out something. On that note Teflon tape remover was not made to actually seal a pipe it was made for lubricant so you can get the fittings back apart 10 years down the road. It helping to seal the threads is only a side bonus if it works.

Comment: **PLEASE**, break up your WALL OF WORDS  into more digestible, **easily read**,  paragraphs. *To review, All though not implicitly stated, your answer to the question is, Yes use putty?* Or is that a "side bonus" of your anecdotal statement.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the putty on top of the rubber. Same as above, if you install correctly it will never leak. I’ve never had a sink leak when using putty and have installed around 100 in last 20 years. There’s a reason they havnt invented a new replacement for putty. Don’t fix something that works perfectly.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. You'll quickly discover that "above" is meaningless around here as answers can change order based on how individual users choose to sort them or based on changes in voting. Also, have you found that adding putty to a rubber gasket violates the manufacturer's warranty? That may be a concern for many people should there ever be a failure.

Answer (score -1):

Yea, don't skip the putty, or something, on the sink parts I'm working on without the putty there is no seal. THREADS ON FITTINGS DO NOT MAKE A WATERTIGHT SEAL. Never have, never will, by virtue of you being able to screw things together, they're not sealed tight.

Comment: Your answer isn't contributing to the question asked. No one mentioned threads on fittings. OP didn't ask if they should skip the "the putty, or something", they asked if they need to use putty WITH the assembly they are working with which comes with washers used for sealing.